# How to color Expander in a DataGrid based on a DataTrigger?

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, datagrid, datatrigger

I have a problem with coloring my `Expander` in the `DataGrid` based on a `DataTrigger`. I have tried many things and red many threads, but without luck.

I want the color to change based on the boolean that are in the `ItemsSource`.

Below it the code that set the `ItemsSource`:

```
private void SetDataGrid(ObservableCollection<SourceInfo> myinfoList)
{
   var ColectList = new ListCollectionView(myinfoList);
   ColectList.GroupDescriptions.Add(new PropertyGroupDescription("DrawNr"));

   MyDataGrid.ItemsSource = ColectList;
}
```

Below is my XAML (the `check` is my parameter in the class that is the itemsource):

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding}"
          Name="MyDataGrid"
          Margin="244,10,20,7"
          AutoGenerateColumns="True"
          CanUserAddRows="False"
          RowEditEnding="MyDataGrid_RowEditEnding"
          Loaded="MyDataGrid_Loaded"
          BorderBrush="{x:Null}"
          Background="{x:Null}"
          HorizontalGridLinesBrush="#FF646464"
          VerticalGridLinesBrush="#FF646464"
          FontFamily="Open Sans">
   <DataGrid.GroupStyle>
      <GroupStyle>
         <GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
               <Setter Property="Margin"
                       Value="0,0,0,5" />
               <Setter Property="Template">
                  <Setter.Value>
                     <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                        <Expander IsExpanded="False"
                                  BorderBrush="#FF002255"
                                  Foreground="Black"
                                  BorderThickness="1,1,1,5">
                           <Expander.Style>
                              <Style TargetType="{x:Type Expander}">
                                 <Setter Property="Background"
                                         Value="Red" />
                                 <Style.Triggers>
                                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=check, RelativeSource={RelativeSource self}}"
                                                 Value="True">
                                       <Setter Property="Background"
                                               Value="Green" />
                                    </DataTrigger>
                                 </Style.Triggers>
                              </Style>
                           </Expander.Style>
                           <Expander.Header>
                              <StackPanel>
                                 <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding DrawNr}" />
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding ItemCount, StringFormat=Count: {0}}"
                                               Margin="30,0,0,0" />
                                 </StackPanel>
                              </StackPanel>
                           </Expander.Header>
                           <Expander.Content>
                              <ItemsPresenter />
                           </Expander.Content>
                        </Expander>
                     </ControlTemplate>
                  </Setter.Value>
               </Setter>
            </Style>
         </GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
      </GroupStyle>
   </DataGrid.GroupStyle>
</DataGrid>
```

The `DataGrid`:

[image: Screenshot of the DataGrid.]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you group a collection view, the data context of a group is a [`CollectionViewGroup`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.collectionviewgroup?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-5.0#properties). It exposes several properties, like the `ItemCount` or `Name`, which is the *value* of the property that you grouped by for the current group. Consequently, if you want to bind the `Expander` header to `DrawNr`, use `Name`.

```
<Expander.Header>
   <StackPanel>
      <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
         <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
         <TextBlock Margin="30,0,0,0" Text="{Binding ItemCount, StringFormat=Count: {0}}" />
      </StackPanel>
   </StackPanel>
</Expander.Header>
```

As for the `check` property, a group can contain *multiple items*, so the `check` property of which item exactly should be considered in the `DataTrigger`, the first, a boolean And of all items, anything else?

Here, I check if there is *exactly one item* in the group and use its `check` property. If it is `True`, the `Expander` background will be green. In all other cases (also for more than one item), it will be red.

```
<Expander.Style>
   <Style TargetType="{x:Type Expander}">
      <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
      <Style.Triggers>
         <MultiDataTrigger>
            <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
               <Condition Binding="{Binding Items.Count}" Value="1" />
               <Condition Binding="{Binding Items[0].Check}" Value="True" />
            </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green" />
         </MultiDataTrigger>
      </Style.Triggers>
   </Style>
</Expander.Style>
```

As a general note, the widely accepted convention for property names is Pascal-Case, e.g. `Check`.